# Single command to open a file or create it and the append data

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I would like to know if in Fortran it is possible to use just a single command (with options/specifiers) to do the following:

1. open a file if it exists and append some data
   (this can be done with: `open(unit=40,file='data.data',Access = 'append',Status='old')` but if the file does not exist a runtime error is issued)
2. create the file if it does not exist and write some data.

I am currently using `inquire` to check whether the file exist or not but then I still have to use the `open` statement to append or write data.

Comment: Please note, that the `access` attribute only allows `"sequential"` or `"direct"` as values. I guess, you meant `position="append"` instead.

Answer (score 34):

As far as I am aware of, the only *safe* solution is to do the way you're already doing it, using different `open` statements for the different cases:

```
program proba
  implicit none

  logical :: exist

  inquire(file="test.txt", exist=exist)
  if (exist) then
    open(12, file="test.txt", status="old", position="append", action="write")
  else
    open(12, file="test.txt", status="new", action="write")
  end if
  write(12, *) "SOME TEXT"
  close(12)
end program proba
```

You may be interested in my [Fortran interface library to libc file system calls (modFileSys)](https://bitbucket.org/aradi/modfilesys), which could at least spare you the logical variable and the `inquire` statement by querying the file status directly:

```
if (file_exists("test.txt")) then
    ...
else
    ...
end if
```

but of course you can program a similar function easily yourself, and especially it won't save you from the two `open` statements...

Comment: The Fortran interface you linked to seems to have been deleted.

Answer (score 9):

```
open(61,file='data.txt',action='write',position='append')
write(61,*) 'hey'
close(61)
```

This will append to an existing file, otherwise create and write. Adding `status='unknown'` would be equivalent.

Answer (score 4):

if you replace the status from 'old' to 'unknown' then you will not get the run time error if the file exists or now.

Thanks

Comment: As far as I know, if `unknown` is specified, the status of the file is file system dependent.

Comment: `unknown` is actually the default status for `open`

Comment: Yes, can't you even just remove the status specifier altogether?

Comment: Also, as pointed out by others it needs to be `position='append'`

Answer (score -1):

In open statement add the attribute `access` as follows;

```
Open(unit=031,file='filename.dat',form='formatted',status='unknown',access='append')
```

The above statement will open the file without destroying old data and write command will append the new lines in the file.
The simplest solution for fortran 90.

Comment: This is not in any way Fortran 90, see the comment below the question. Also note the `access='append'`is in the question already. Maybe you meant something as Nick in his answer below?

Comment: oh ya, I made a mistake. Yes, instead of access, I should have mention about status, but any way that was already answered.I was quite hurry in understanding the question. Thanks.