# Opening files specifying status and position

Tags: io, fortran

According to [this source](http://www.lahey.com/docs/lfenthelp/F95AROPENStmt.htm), I would interpret that specifying status="old" should append by default:

> **OLD**, if the file is to be opened but not replaced

However, that is not what is happening in my codes. Here is an example:

```
program openstat_test
   implicit none
   integer :: mystat

   mystat=0
   print*,"Im trying to open a new file..."
   open( unit=100, file="output.txt", status="new", iostat=mystat )
   if ( mystat == 17 ) then
      print*,"File already exists; overwriting!"
      open( unit=100, file="output.txt", status="replace", iostat=mystat )
   end if
   if ( mystat /= 0 ) then
      print*, "Error prevents test..."; stop
   end if
   write( unit=100, fmt=* ) "Line number 1"
   close( unit=100)

   print*,"Im trying to open an old file..."
   open( unit=100, file="output.txt", status="old", iostat=mystat )
   if ( mystat /= 0 ) then
      print*, "Error prevents test..."; stop
   end if
   write( unit=100, fmt=* ) "Line number 2"
   close( unit=100)

   print*,"Im trying to open an old file AND FORCING APPEND..."
   open( unit=100, file="output.txt", status="old", position="append", iostat=mystat )
   if ( mystat /= 0 ) then
      print*, "Error prevents test..."; stop
   end if
   write( unit=100, fmt=* ) "Line number 3"
   close( unit=100)

end program openstat_test
```

("output.txt" only has "Line number 2" and "Line number 3"; the second open that uses status="old" is overwriting)

Am I'm missing something? Do you always need to specify position="append" even with status="old"? If so, why does the reference specify that "old" means opening but not replacing if the default writing command will overwrite the file?

Analogously, would it be safe to use position="append" without status (or with "unknown") to either create a new file or if the file exists append to it? I tried it and it works, but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15526203/single-command-to-open-a-file-or-create-it-and-the-append-data) says that the safe way to do it is case selecting without really explaining why or what could go wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a filesystem level there may well be differences between deleting a file then creating one with the same name and overwriting the contents of a file.  This could relate to attributes or permissions and so on.

`status='old'` means that the named file exists at the time of connection.  `status='replace'` for a file which exists first deletes the file and then creates a new one with the same name.

As you can see, then, it is reasonable for `status='old'` to lead to overwriting.  The reference you quote doesn't say exactly what the Fortran standard says.

Without giving `position=...` the default is `'asis'`.  In the case where a file isn't currently connected the file position is left unspecified.  If you wish to append you should explicitly give `position='append'`.

With `status='unknown'` (the default) the status is processor dependent.  It isn't possible to definitively say what that means.

Comment: So you should **always** specify the status, because some processors may decide that the default is either "old" (thus returning errors if the file doesn't exist) or "new" (idem but when files already exist)? The "common" behavior is something different than old/new/replace? Because in my case when I don't specify the status, it doesn't complain if the file exists nor if it doesn't. If this "I don't care" behavior exists, why isn't there an option for forcing the processor to use it?

Comment: I'm not aware of a system where `'unknown'` causes problems.  That said, if you are not caring about the file, `'replace'` may well fit best.